# xml parsing to do iteration

Tags: xml, parsing

I have a xml file

```
<PhysicalTable mdsid="mc000002a-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">
        <name>FCT_PBCS</name>
        <xmlnsxsi>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xmlnsxsi>
        <xmlns>http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository</xmlns>
        <type>none</type> 
        <maxConn>0</maxConn>
        <containerRef>"/oracle/bi/server/base/Schema/80000002-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000.xml#m80000002-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000"</containerRef>
   </PhysicalTable>
   <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002b-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">
        <name>ACCT_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE </dataType>
        <precision>22</precision> 
        <nullable>true</nullable> 
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002c-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>CURR_ID</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
    <PhysicalColumn mdsid = "mc000002d-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">    
        <name>DATE_KEY</name>
        <dataType>DOUBLE</dataType> 
        <precision>22</precision>
        <nullable>true</nullable>
        <specialType>none</specialType>
    </PhysicalColumn>
```

Im trying to parse and put all the values in a Data frame

```
for node in xroot.findall("PhysicalColumn"):
    s_mdsid = node.attrib.get("mdsid")
    s_name = node.find("name").text if node is not None else None
    s_dataType = node.find("dataType").text if node is not None else None
    s_precision = node.find("precision").text if node is not None else None
    s_nullable = node.find("nullable").text if node is not None else None
    s_specialType = node.find("specialType").text if node is not None else None
        
rows.append({"mdsid": s_mdsid, "name": s_name, 
              "dataType": s_dataType, "precision": s_precision , "nullable" : s_nullable ,"specialType" : s_specialType})

out_df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols1)
```

but the out_df1 gives only the last children value , its not iterating . But when i print its giving me the whole childrens list . I have to put in a data frame and copy to excel.Can someone pls help ?

Output that im getting

```
    mdsid                                   name    dataType    precision   nullable    specialType
0   mc0000037-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000   YEAR_YY DOUBLE      22          true        none
```

Im expecting like

```
    mdsid                                   name    dataType    precision   nullable    specialType
0   mc000002b-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000   ACCT_ID DOUBLE      22          true        none
1   mc000002b-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000   CURR_ID DOUBLE      22          true        none
....
13  mc0000037-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000   YEAR_YY DOUBLE      22          true        none
```

Thanks,
Aarush

Comment: check the indentation of the rows.append line, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this and see if it works:

```
rows = []
for node in xroot.findall("PhysicalColumn"):
    s_mdsid = node.attrib.get("mdsid")  
    s_name = node.find("name").text if node is not None else None    
    s_dataType = node.find("dataType").text if node is not None else None
    s_precision = node.find("precision").text if node is not None else None
    s_nullable = node.find("nullable").text if node is not None else None
    s_specialType = node.find("specialType").text if node is not None else None
    row = []
    row.extend([s_mdsid, s_name,s_dataType, s_precision,s_nullable,s_specialType])
    rows.append(row)
columns = ["mdsid","name","dataType","precision","nullable","specialType"]
out_df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
out_df1
```

The output should be something like your expected output.

Comment: @Aarush If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer, please.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can i find that option to accept the answer ??I dont see anywhere options like that ..

Comment: @Aarush There's something strange about your account - you don't seem the have to option to accept (it's usually a checkmark above the clapping hands); only to upvote or downvote....

Comment: @Aarush Try clicking on the clapping hands and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I accepted the answer , I have posted another question , can you pls clarify if my understanding is correct ??

Comment: @Aarush I'll be happy to take a look - but you're going about it wrong: don't post a new question as an answer to an old question; post it as a new question; this way everyone can see it and chime in.

Comment: sorry about it ..Sure will post as a new question .- Aarush

Answer (score 0):

I have one more question . My actual XML file was some thing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<DECLARE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository/admin">
<Database mdsid="m80000001-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000" name="PBCS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository" type="Oracle11g" dbName="Oracle 11g" dbTypeId="57">
<Feature name="LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="FULL_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="NESTED_OUTER_JOIN_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="UNION_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="UNION_ALL_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="COUNT_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="COUNT_DISTINCT_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="COUNT_STAR_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
<Feature name="SUM_SUPPORTED" value="true"/>
</Database>
<PhysicalTable mdsid="mc000002a-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000" name="FCT_PBCS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/obis/repository" type="none" maxConn="0" containerRef="/oracle/bi/server/base/Schema/80000002-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000.xml#m80000002-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000">
<PhysicalColumn mdsid="mc000002b-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000" name="ACCT_ID" dataType="DOUBLE" precision="22" nullable="true" specialType="none">
</PhysicalColumn>
<PhysicalColumn mdsid="mc000002c-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000" name="CURR_ID" dataType="DOUBLE" precision="22" nullable="true" specialType="none">
</PhysicalColumn>
<PhysicalColumn mdsid="mc000002d-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000" name="DATE_KEY" dataType="DOUBLE" precision="22" nullable="true" specialType="none">
</PhysicalColumn>
<PhysicalColumn mdsid="mc000002e-469e-1667-ba67-0a890c480000" name="ENTITY_ID" dataType="DOUBLE" precision="22" nullable="true" specialType="none">
</PhysicalColumn>
</PhysicalTable>
```

Will Element tree parse a parse like that without proper alignment of root or attributes??

I thought it cannot parse and gave suggestion to change the input file as in my previous question that i posted .

Is my understanding correct ??? Can some one clarify

Thanks
Aarush